# Redis Caching Structure use Case

Tags: redis

**Problem Statement** : One of our module(Ticket module - store procedure ) is taking 4- 5 sec to return the data from DB. This store procedure supports 7 -8 filters + it has joins on 4- 5 tables to get the text of the IDs stored in Ticket tables eg ( Client name, Ticket Status, TicketType ... ) and this has hampered the performance of the SP.

**Current Tech stack** : ASP.Net 4.0 Web API , MS SQL 2008

We are planning to introduce Redis as a caching server and Node js with the aim of improving the performance and scalability.

**Use case** : We have Service ticket module and its has following attributes

1. TicketId
2. ClientId
3. TicketDate
4. Ticket Status
5. Ticket Type

Each user of this module has access to fix no of clients ie

- User1 have access to tickets of Client 1, 2, 3, 4......
- User2 have access to tickets of Client 1, 2, 5, 7......

So basically when User1 accesses the Ticket module he should be able to filter service tickets on TicketId, Client, Ticket Date ( from and To) , Ticket Status (Open, Hold, In Process ...) and Ticket Type ( Request, Complaint, Service .....) + Since User1 has access of only Client 1 ,2 3, 4......, caching should only give the list of tickets of the clients he has access of.

Would appreciate if you guys can share your views how should we structure the Redis ie what should we use for each of the above items ie hashset, set, sorted set ... + how should we filter the tickets depending on the access of client resp user has.

Answer (score 0):

Redis is a key/value storage. I would use hashset with a structure like:
Key: ticketId
Subkeys: clientId, ticketDate, ticketStatus, ticketType

Search, sorting etc - handle programmatically from application or/and in LUA.

Comment: Perfect !. We have used Hashset to store the whole Ticket Objects and Sets for maintaining indexes for filtering eg TicketStatus_Open,TicketStatus_Closed, TicketType_Request....... and so on. But we are stuck at, once we get the list of ticket Ids post filtering ,how do I reduce the TicketId list to the list of TicketIds of the clients ( as describe above) that particular user have access of or looping through each ticket in the filtered list and checking whether the user has access of the client of the resp ticket is only the solution –